# Get short-term database changes on database move

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy, backup, restore

Database DB_B is a copy of DB_A. DB_B is less than an hour old but DB_A is live until the users are switched over to DB_B. How do I track the changes made during that interval? I will know the time that the copy was made. I can't be adding extra columns or tables to DB_A unless they are small changes and/or don't affect business.

This is my current script. Can I do better than this?

```
SELECT
   [name]
  ,create_date
  ,modify_date
FROM
   sys.views
WHERE
   modify_date > '26 July 2023 15:50:00'
```

Idealy I would like anough information from DB_A to create an insert/update script on DB_B

Is this possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is on MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for transaction log or replication.

https://blog.pythian.com/monitoring-transaction-logs-in-postgresql/

https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-set-up-postgresql-database-replication

Or, triggers might also work:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

And if none of those options work, query a timestamp on every column.